# Obtener palabras ubicadas entre una palabra y otra en Python

Tags: python

Me gustaría obtener una serie de palabras en una cadena de texto en Python, mas concretamente en una sentencia SQL, por ejemplo:

`"SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE...;"`

Me gustaría extraer las palabras entre `FROM y WHERE (tab1)` y almacenarla en una variable.

Y si hay más de una palabra entre `FROM y WHERE`, ejemplo: `"SELECT * FROM tab1,tab2 WHERE..."`pues que la variable sea `False`

Por ejemplo:

```
sql1="SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE ip=1"
```

Desde esta variable con un String me gustaría almacenar en un variable el nombre de la tabla (que es tab1), y si hay más de una tabla, la variable almacenará `False`

Comment: Muestra lo que tienes hasta el momento...

Comment: Tengo de momento eso, estoy determinando las posiciones de FROM y WHERE para saber si dentro de estos 2 hay 1 palabra o más, pero ahí me atasco jeje

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede resolver usando expresiones regulares.

La expresión "FROM (\w+) WHERE" reconoce frases con exactamente una variable. Si la frase no tiene una variable, o más de una, la expresión no será reconocida.

Usamos `re.compile` para compilar la expresión regular y hacer más rápida la búsqueda.

Con `re.search` podemos buscar la expresión regular en toda la cadena de entrada, no solo desde el principio. Si se encuentra la expresión regular, entonces la función retorna un *match object* contiendo los resultados capturados por la expresión regular. En este caso, sólo hay un grupo de captura en la expresión regular. Entonces, `m[1]` contiene el nombre de la variable usada.

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"FROM (\w+) WHERE")

tests = ["", "FROM", "WHERE", "FROM WHERE", "FROM TAB1 WHERE", "FROM TAB1, TAB2 WHERE",
         'sql="SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE ip=1"']

for test in tests:
    m = patron.search(test)
    if m:
        var =  m[1]
        print(f"Texto '{test}', variable '{var}'")
    else:
        print(f"Texto '{test}' no contiene variable.")
```

produce:

```
Texto '' no contiene variable.
Texto 'FROM' no contiene variable.
Texto 'WHERE' no contiene variable.
Texto 'FROM WHERE' no contiene variable.
Texto 'FROM TAB1 WHERE', variable 'TAB1'
Texto 'FROM TAB1, TAB2 WHERE' no contiene variable.
Texto 'sql=SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE ip=1', variable 'tab1'
```

Comment: Me aparece este error: Anomalous backslash in string: '\w'. String constant might be missing an r prefix.

Comment: Puedes anteponer la 'r', dejandolo en `re.compile(r"FROM (\w+) WHERE")`. Funciona lo mismo

Comment: No me funciona con una variable con texto

Comment: ¿Qué son variables con texto? La pregunta no las menciona ...

Comment: sql="SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE ip=1" , por ejemplo

Comment: No se que haces. En todo caso edite la pregunta para incluir el ejemplo que das y lo procesa bien, como puedes chequear.

Answer (score 0):

también podrías solo usar cortes de cadena:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE ip=1"


sub = sql[sql.find('FROM')+4:sql.find('WHERE')].split()
if len(sub) > 1:
   sub = False
else:
   sub = "".join(sub)
print(f"Sql FROM tiene como parámetro a: {sub}")
```